# Is it possible to chain instructions in an ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ngmodel

I've got a couple of sliders I want to pick from a menu.
As a consequence, I need to both pick the right slider and reset the first slide to 0.
I have a slide model I set to 0 fro the `ng-click` just before opening the popup, but, unfortunately, slide is not reset to 0.
Any idea?

PS: I don't want to move the slide variable to the scope of the controller.

```
<div ng-init="slide = 0"></div>

<div 
    ng-repeat="s in sliders"
    style="left:{{s.center.x - 70}}px; top:{{s.center.y}}px"
    ng-click="slide = 0; openPopover('#slides-{{s.name}}')"
    >
    {{s.displayName}}
</div>
```

Comment: try `$parent.slide = 0` (`slide` as is, is local to the ng-repeat scope).

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi, that was the right answer. Please, write it down into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It's possible as mentioned in the answer, but don't do this, make a function in the controller.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) creates it's own scope, your current code will set `slide` to `0` inside these scopes. A quick (and maybe dirty) way is to use `$parent` to directly reference the parent-scope. E.g:

```
ng-click="$parent.slide = 0; openPopover('#slides-{{s.name}}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's a valid angularjs/js expression it will work

http://plnkr.co/edit/wta6GcVZHVccVbCf08IT?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-click="set = 'Cowa'; to = 'bunga!'; popup('test')">Hello {{name}}!{{set}}{{to}}</p>
</body>
```